# Is it possible to restrict a tag to certain environments in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've got a tag that I want to trigger in Live, but not Staging environment. Since it's a Custom HTML Tag I could do `if {{Environment Name}}...` But I'm wondering if there's a more generic way that works for all types of tags as I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be to use the environment name in a trigger. In your scenario, you could create a "staging environment" trigger and add it as a blocking trigger.

To make the blocking trigger apply to all possible events, you would create it as a custom event trigger, check the "use regex" checkbox and enter ".*" as event name. Then you select as condition "fires only when {{Environment Name}} equals Staging" (or whatever the exact name of your staging env is). The regex makes sure the trigger is blocking on both built-in (pageview, DOM ready etc) and custom events.